# Como mostrar select option com jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho um select box que esta como `display:none` e quero que ao ao clicar num botão aparece a listagem para o utilizador escolher mas não estou a conseguir fazer gostava que me dessem algumas luzes de como fazer.

HTML

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <div class="input_home_pequisa">Escolha um distrito 
            <img id="botao_distritos" style="float:right; cursor:pointer; margin-top:4px;" src="img/select_home.png">
            <select style="display:none;" name="teste" id="teste">
              <option value="">teste</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <div class="input_home_pequisa">Escolha um concelho 
            <img id="botao_concelhos" style="float:right; margin-top:4px; cursor:pointer;" src="img/select_home.png">
            <select style="display:none;" name="concelhos" id="concelhos">
              <option value="">teste</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <div class="input_home_pequisa">Escolha uma categoria 
            <img id="botao_categoria" style="float:right; margin-top:4px; cursor:pointer;" src="img/select_home.png">
            <select style="display:none;" name="categoria" id="categoria">
              <option value="">teste</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <div style="margin-top:-5px;">
            <a href="#" class="botao_home_pesquisa"><i class="ico i-search"></i></a>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Qual é o elemento `button`, ou seja qual é o botão?

Comment: E o a imagem que contem em cada div

Comment: E o que deve acontecer qualdo se clica em cada imagem específica? ambas mostram o mesmo `select`? o conteudo do `select` muda?

Comment: o conteudo do select muda eu quero que ao clicar em cada imagem mostra a listagem dos option

Comment: E de onde vem essa listagem? servidor? ajax?

Comment: Não de um select que esta no html mas que esta como display:none

Comment: E onde está esse select? vejo 2 imagens mas só um select.

Comment: Eu só pus um select para teste para ver se consiga fazer mas não consegui e por isso e quero saber ter uma ideia de como posso fazer depois o resto dos select eu faço

Comment: Eu não vou dar resposta se o teu HTML nõ é o que usas na verdade. Preciso saber a estrutura para montar código que vá buscar o select certo ao DOM clicando na imagem certa. Sem saber onde o outro select está não vejo como te posso ajudar sem te confundir ainda mais...

Comment: editei o html agora esta como eu quero utilizar

Comment: O que queres dizer com "mostrar listagem das options mas não o select""?

Comment: Sim mostrar só a listagem das option quando clicas num select aparece a listagem dos options e isso que quero que so apareça

Comment: Para perceberes melhor o que eu quero neste link tem la exatamente o que eu pretendo logo na home tens la um select eu quero que faça dessa forma http://themewoop.com/preview/?item=direct_html

Comment: Referes-te ao link "Direct wordpress" no canto superior esquerdo?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23734/discussion-between-sergio-and-cesar-sousa).

Comment: Estás por aí? dá um salto ao chat ^

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue isso buscando a *div-pai* e em seguida o respectivo `select`:

```js
$(".input_home_pequisa img").on("click", function(){
   $(this).closest('div').find('select').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <div class="input_home_pequisa">Escolha um distrito 
            <img id="botao_distritos" style="float:right; cursor:pointer; margin-top:4px;" src="https://project-firefly.com/sites/all/themes/project_firefly_2_0/img/header-submit-button.png">
            <select style="display:none;" name="teste" id="teste">
              <option value="">teste</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <div class="input_home_pequisa">Escolha um concelho 
            <img id="botao_concelhos" style="float:right; margin-top:4px; cursor:pointer;" src="https://project-firefly.com/sites/all/themes/project_firefly_2_0/img/header-submit-button.png">
            <select style="display:none;" name="concelhos" id="concelhos">
              <option value="">teste</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <div class="input_home_pequisa">Escolha uma categoria 
            <img id="botao_categoria" style="float:right; margin-top:4px; cursor:pointer;" src="https://project-firefly.com/sites/all/themes/project_firefly_2_0/img/header-submit-button.png">
            <select style="display:none;" name="categoria" id="categoria">
              <option value="">teste</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <div style="margin-top:-5px;">
            <a href="#" class="botao_home_pesquisa"><i class="ico i-search"></i></a>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```